# Change viewpager and viewpager item size dynamically with listview scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a `listview` below a `viewpager` and in the initial state (when nothing has been scrolled), the `viewpager` shows only one item with a 10dp "preview" of the next and previous items (I have achieved this by setting a negative page margin:`viewPager.setPageMargin(-48);`). What I am trying to do is, on scrolling down the `listview`:

1) the `listview` should "push" the `viewpager` up, decreasing its height up to a certain point. On reaching that point (some minHeight for the viewpager), the `listview` should scroll normally with the smaller sized `viewpager` above it.

2) The next and the previous items in the `viewpager` should pull inside (towards the central item) and in the final state, **three** items of the `viewpager` should be fully displayed. (Images below to illustrate this)

Scrolling up the listview should do the opposite.

I have managed to do part (1) of my task. Here's the code

My `viewpager` and `listview` are inside a `FrameLayout` like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:scrollbars="none" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I "fake" the `listview` to be below the `viewpager` by adding a `transaprent` header view to the `listview` and making the heights of both the `headeview` and the `viewpager` same. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
screenWidth = // Screen width of the phone
headerHeight = // Required height of the viewpager and the headerview

headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fake_list_header, listView, false);
headerView.getLayoutParams().height = headerHeight;
headerView.getLayoutParams().width = screenWidth;
viewPager.getLayoutParams().height = headerHeight;
viewPager.getLayoutParams().width = screenWidth;
viewPager.setPageMargin(negativeMargin);
listView.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);

// Other initializations and stuff
```

fake_list_header layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, my `listview` **`OnScrollListener`** that takes care of adjusting the `viewpager` height depending on the amount scrolled by the `listview` and stopping when we reach the minimum height for the `viewpager`:

```
    OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            if (listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
                View firstChild = listview.getChildAt(1);   // 0th element is the fake headerview itself
                int topY = 0;
                if (firstChild != null) {
                    topY = firstChild.getTop();

                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    layoutParams.width = screenWidth;
                    layoutParams.height = topY;

                    if (topY < headerHeight && topY >= minHeight) {
                        // minHeight is the minimum height the viewpager takes, after this point it stops getting smaller 
                        //And vice-versa with headerHeight taking care of the maximum height the viewpager can take

                        viewpager.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);                          
                    }
                }


            }

        }
    }
```

Part (2) of my task is where I am stuck (and running out of ideas), I have tried changing `pageMargin` of the `viewpager` with the scroll but the results aren't good (also don't think it is the right approach for achieving something like this). Setting X position of the next(or previous) view in the pager by calling `setTranslationX` with scroll also isn't working.

Here are some mocks of what I am trying to achieve:

**Initial state (nothing scrolled)**

[image]

**Final state (minHeight of viewpager achieved)**

[image]

Is using `viewpager` and a `listview` right way of achieving something like this? I thought of using a horizontal `recyclerview` instead of a `viewpager`, but I need the "page by page" scroll behavior of a `viewpager` for the horizontal scroll/swipe of items. Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your main layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you explain how this might work? you just seem to be setting a height to the viewpager

Comment: I also take the RelativeLayout behalf of Frame Layout and  and in listview                    use property android:layout_below="@+id/pager".

Comment: but that doesn't fix what I am trying to slove